# Share folder with specific users from other machines without creating another account in the sharing PC?

Tags: permissions, network-shares, user-accounts, file-sharing

I researched the site and I know you have the same account on the PC that is going to share the files in order to share only to specific accounts, but this seems messy to me.

Imagine you can share a lot of different folders to different people, it could become a mess to have so many accounts in your PC you don't even use.

Isn't there any other way without using domains or third party software?

In the windows where you add accounts for the share permissions, theres a button that says "location" and there appears your own machines name. However I wonder why a PC could not detect another PC and it's created accounts to add them to share permissions list. Isn't it possible in any way?

Isn't there a way by typing specifically a full user path with the workgroup or machine and account name?

Comment: You could, in theory, just use a seperate machine or VM and use that to share files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miscomprehension is *"it could become a mess to have so many accounts in your PC you don't even use."* - you actually do use them: To authenticate and then authorize users to access your shares.

If you were to delegate this process of authentication and authorization to another machine, there are only two possible outcomes:

- you use a mutually trusted machine: This is what a domain is primarily about, just call the anchor of this trust a domain controller
- you use the other user's untrusted machine: Why hassle with passwords at all? Everyone can access anything you share, as a machine under their own control is in charge.

So basically: If you want your computer to enforce sharing privileges, **your** computer must be able to authenticate and authorize the other user - either by asking a DC or by having the accounts set up locally.

Comment: Then is there any way accounts don't show up in the login screen on windows' start? Can I hide other accounts in the login screen?
Since managing Windows Server for home may be too much, creating other users seems the only thing I can do as you say.

Comment: You can hide the user accounts as you have accessed. The process is the same on different Windows versions: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.windowscentral.com/how-hide-specific-user-accounts-sign-screen-windows-10%3famp